# Programmatically create a user and assign a role

Tags: 7, users

I'm programmatically creating a user with the following code.

```
$newUser = array(
  'name' => $mail, 
  'pass' => 'password',  // note: do not md5 the password
  'mail' => $mail, 
  'status' => 1, 
  'init' => $mail,
  'roles' => array(5)
);
$user = user_save(null, $newUser);
```

I have got a role with the role ID equal to 5; when I create the user, in the table "users_roles" there is only a row with the value 0 for the role ID, but if I print the user object with `var_dump()`, it looks like the roles are created.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It only checks for truthiness on the value, the key is what matters. `array($role_id => 'anything')`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This code worked for me:

```
$new_user = array(
  'name' => $name,
  'pass' => $sifra, // note: do not md5 the password
  'mail' => $email,
  'status' => 1,
  'init' => $email,
  'roles' => array(
    DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID => 'authenticated user',
    3 => 'custom role',
  ),
);

// The first parameter is sent blank so a new user is created.
user_save('', $new_user);
```

Comment: Should i write the password a password like "abc12345" and user_save() will convert into md5?

Comment: `user_save` will take care of it

Comment: As long as the password is in `user_save()`'s second argument, it will get hashed.  If you do `user_save($account)` without the `$edit` argument, then md5 conversion doesn't happen.  The answer by @SMTF below demonstrates this.

Comment: Thanks saved my day

Answer (score 16):

To programmatically create a user with roles and custom field values (like e.g. First Name and Last Name) you can use the following code:

```
$new_user = array(
  'name' => 'xgramp',
  'pass' => 'idontwantnoonebutyoutoloveme',
  'mail' => 'xgparsons@flyingburritobrothers.la',
  'signature_format' => 'full_html',
  'status' => 1,
  'language' => 'en',
  'timezone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  'init' => 'Email',
  'roles' => array(
    DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID => 'authenticated user',
    6 => 'member', // role id for custom roles varies per website
  ),
  'field_first_name' => array(
    'und' => array(
      0 => array(
        'value' => 'Gram',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'field_last_name' => array(
    'und' => array(
      0 => array(
        'value' => 'Parsons',
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

$account = user_save(NULL, $new_user);
```

See this blog post and the comments for more details:
http://codekarate.com/blog/create-user-account-drupal-7-programmatically

Answer (score 13):

This is an example I found on a site.

```
$account = new stdClass;
$account->is_new = TRUE;
$account->name = 'foo';
$account->pass = user_hash_password('bar');
$account->mail = 'foo@example.com';
$account->init = 'foo@example.com';
$account->status = TRUE;
$account->roles = array(DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID => TRUE);
$account->timezone = variable_get('date_default_timezone', '');
user_save($account);
```

Comment: Sorry, I think the DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID => TRUE  seems wrong, and I don't think user_hash_password is needed.

Comment: `user_hash_password('bar');` is wrong

Comment: There are some instances where `user_save()` fails to hash passwords before saving them (in my own experience and I see others around the web also experiencing it occasionally).  I don't know why (but I'd like to!).  In these cases calling `user_hash_password()` seems necessary.

Comment: The code in this answer **does** require `user_hash_password()` to be called manually.  This is because it's not passing `$edit` to the `user_save()`.  If the code includes `$edit = array('pass' => 'bar');` (which this answer does not) then instead of doing `$account->pass = user_hash...` you can do `user_save($account, $edit);` and `user_save()` will do the hashing for you.

Answer (score 3):

To create a user programmatically from an e-mail address, try this:

```
// Use the e-mail address prefix as a user name.
$name = substr($mail, 0, strpos($mail, '@'));

// Make sure the user name isn't already taken.
$query = db_select('users', 'u')
  ->fields('u', array('uid'))
  ->condition('u.name', $name)
  ->execute();
$result = $query->fetch();

// If the user name is taken, append a random string to the end of it.
if ($result->uid) { $name .= '-' . user_password(); }

// Build the user account object and then save it.
$account = new stdClass();
$account->name = $name;
$account->mail = $mail;
$account->init = $mail;
$account->pass = user_password();
$account->status = 1;
user_save($account);
if ($account->uid) {
  drupal_set_message('Created new user with id %uid', array('%uid' => $account->uid));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To create user in Drupal 8

```
  // Mandatory user creation settings
  use Drupal\user\Entity\User;
  $user = User::create();
  $language = 'en'; //you can set your language
  $email = 'test@gmail.com';
  $user_name = 'ajay_gadhavana';
  $user->enforceIsNew();
  $user->setPassword('Password');
  $user->setEmail($email);
  $user->setUsername($user_name); // This username must be unique and accept only a-Z,0-9, - _ @ .
  $user->set("langcode", $language);
  // Optional settings
  $user->set("init", $email);
  $user->set("preferred_langcode", $language);
  $user->set("preferred_admin_langcode", $language);
  $user->activate();
  // Add a role to user
  $user->addRole('administrator');
  //Save user
  $user->save();`
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a user programmatically:

```
$newUser = array(
      'name' => 'theUserName,
      'pass' => 'thePassWord',
      'mail' => 'the@mail.com',
      'status' => 1,
      'roles' => array(DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID => 'authenticated user'),
      'init' =>  'the@mail.com',
  );
user_save(null, $newUser);
```