# Create a new user programmatically and mimic the registration flow?

Tags: 7, users

I notice we already have an example for programmatically creating a new user in [Create a user programmatically and give they a role](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6976/create-a-user-programmatically-and-give-him-a-role). However, this example uses `user_save()`, which does not mimic the registration process, (e.g. no email is sent to the user).

Could I use [user_register_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_register_submit)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear on what your overall goals are here. However, you might check out the [Form Clerk](http://drupal.org/project/form_clerk) module. You can use it to create users, as well as many other things.

> Form Clerk is an administrative utility that provides a semi-automated way to input data into a Drupal form. Multiple instances of form data can be entered with one command. For example, multiple users with varying permissions can be created, or multiple articles with arbitrary content can be added.