# Auto Increment on users table is not functioning

Tags: 7, users

I need to Create a new user programmatically. So, I have used `user_save` method, as shown here:

```
$usersave = array(
'name' => 'abc',
'pass' => 'abc',
'mail' => 'abc@gmail.com',
'status' => 1,
'roles' => array(
  DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID => 'authenticated user',
      5 => 'customer'
),
);

$save = user_save($usersave);
```

But it throws this error message:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO {users} (name, pass, mail, status) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => abc [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => abc [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => abc@gmail.com [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 1 ) in drupal_write_record() (line 7383 of /home/vijay/public_html/vssb/public/includes/common.inc).

What's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [Create a user programmatically and give they a role](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6976/create-a-user-programmatically-and-give-they-a-role)

```
// The first parameter should be blank so a new user is created.
user_save('', $new_user);
```

If you want to use `user_save($new_user);` you can set `$new_user->is_new` to TRUE or omit the $account->uid field.